# Drawing a figure with edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a picture that would look complexity-wise like this

[image]

But instead of making it rectangular-looking, I need to make it triangular-looking that would look something like this (but will similar comments surrounding the figure). Thank you for any feedback.

[image]

```
\usepackage{tiki}

\begin{center}
\tikz {
  \node[draw,rectangle] (a) at (0,2) [rounded rectangle] {Sales Response};
\node[draw,rectangle] (b) at (5,2) [rounded rectangle] {Optimal Labor};
\node[draw,rectangle] (d) at (2,0) [rounded rectangle] {Profit Maximization};
\draw (a) edge[->] (b)
      (b) edge[->] (d) (d) edge[<-] (a);

}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by completing it suitably. That is much more useful than a mere fragment of code, especially one which mixes preamble with document commands and loads an imaginary package :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another verbose solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5 cm,
block/.style = { rectangle,draw,  rounded corners, text width = 4 cm, minimum height = 2cm, align = center},
arrow/.style = {-Triangle,  very thick}]

\node[block](optimal){Optimal Labor \\$L_{it}^{*} = f(N_{i,t - p})$ };
\node[block, above left = of optimal](sales){Sales Response \\ $S_{it}= f(N_{it}, L_{it})$};
\node[block, above right = of optimal](profit){Profit maximization\\ $(\pi(L_{it}), \pi(\hat{L}_{it} ), \pi(L_{it}))$};

\draw[arrow] (sales.south) -- node[left, xshift = -0.5cm, yshift = -0.5cm, text width = 2cm, align = center]{Estimates of \\ $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$}(optimal.north);
\draw[arrow](optimal.north)--node[right, xshift = 0.5cm, yshift = -0.5cm, text width = 2cm, align = center]{Estimates of\\ $(\theta_{o}, \theta_{p}, d)$}(profit.south);
\draw[arrow](sales)--node[above, text width = 2cm, align = center]{Estimates of \\ $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$}(profit);

\node[above]at(sales.north){Fit Sample (Weeks 1 - 40)};
\node[above]at(profit.north){Test Samples (Weeks 41 -- 52)};
\node[below right, yshift = -1.5cm, text width = 2cm, align = left]at(profit.south){$h = \dfrac{\pi(\hat{L}_{it})}{\pi(L_{it} ^{*})}$ \\ [5pt] $a = \dfrac{\pi(L_{it} ^{a})}{\pi(L_{it} ^{*})}$  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, some of your arrows are pointing in the wrong direction. "Sales response" and "profit maximization" should point into "optimal labor".

Answer (score 4):

This is an annotated version of a Minimal Working Example based on a corrected version of the code posted in the question.

Colours are used to indicate which elements of the existing diagram are associated with particular labels.

- Blue, red and green show labels added to the three nodes as part of the `\node` operation.
- Orange, magenta and cyan-blue show labels added to the three edges as part of the `edge` operation using the `quotes` library.

In the case of the node labels, `every label` is used to allow multi-line labels, with centre alignment.

`every edge quotes` is used to achieve the same for the edge labels. This makes it possible to write `"<label>"` in the style options for the edge and `"<label>"'` to swap the position by flipping it across the path to the other side.

The locations of the node labels are specified using either a specified angle (e.g. `-5`) or a description (e.g. `below`). In some cases, the position is adjusted by giving the `anchor` for the node label.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={align=center}, every edge quotes/.append style={align=center}]
  \node [draw, blue, rounded rectangle, label={[blue]left:Here is a label\\left of a node}, label={[blue]above:This diagram has\\many too many\\labels \dots}] (a) at (0,2)  {Sales Response};
  \node [draw, red, rounded rectangle, label={[red]above:Here is a long label\\above a node}] (b) at (5,2)  {Optimal Labor};
  \node [draw, green!75!black, rounded rectangle, label={[green!75!black]below:Here is a long label\\below a node}, label={[green!75!black,anchor=north east]-175:Yet another\\label}, label={[green!75!black,anchor=west]-5:Still another}] (d) at (2,0)  {Profit Maximization};
  \draw (a) edge [->, blue!50!cyan, "Something here", "and there"'] (b) (b) edge [->, magenta, "Something everywhere\\and nowhere"] (d) (d) edge [<-, orange, "An unlabelled edge", "\& a paradox"'] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: label variations]

Answer (score 3):

Please post a M[W]E next time. Here is an illustration of how to place nodes close to existing nodes or lines :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\tikz {
\node[draw, rounded rectangle] (a) at (0,2) {Sales Response};
\node[draw, rounded rectangle] (b) at (5,2) {Optimal Labor};
\node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, text width=2cm] (d) at (2,0) {Profit Maximization};
\draw (a) edge[->] node[above] {hello} (b)
      (b) edge[->] node[right] {hi!} (d) 
      (d) edge[<-] node[above, sloped] {comment} (a);
\node[above] at (a.north) {some text};
\node[below] at (d.south) {more text};

}
\end{center}
```

Plus I changed the shape of node (d) to come closer to your original example.
[image]